# Python does not save results to database

Tags: python

Ok, there is an API that returns a json format like this:

```
{
  "count": 111,
  "people": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "kael",
      "owner": {
        "login": "kael@...",
        "id": 112
      },
      "followers": 18856,
      "popularity": 1.0
    },{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "das",
      "owner": {
        "login": "das@...",
        "id": 122
      },
      "followers": 188356,
      "popularity": 133
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to fetch these from url `http://api.example.com/people/get` and submit the result to database. For that this is the code.

```
import json, MySQLdb, urllib2, time

# database object
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","foo","bar")
x = db.cursor()

# API url
url = "http://api.example.com/people/get"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
jsonString = response.read()
toJson = json.loads(jsonString)

# result counts
total_count =  toJson['count']


i = 1

pages = total_count / 100
while (i < pages):

    _url = "http://api.example.com/people/get/page"+ str(i) +"&per_page=100"

    _response = urllib2.urlopen(_url)
    _jsonString = _response.read()
    _toJson = json.loads(_jsonString)

    user = _toJson['people']



    for r in user:
        user_id = r['id']
        name = r['name']      
        full_name  = r['full_name'] 
        url = r['url']            

        try: 
            x.execute("""INSERT INTO repos (id, name, f_name, url) 
            VALUES ('%d', '%s', '%s', '%s') """, (user_id, name, full_name  , url))
            db.commit()
        except:
            db.rollback()


    i += 1
db.close()
```

I don't know if the above script has logic problems, because it is not working. There is no data being submited to database.

Comment: You should add debugging output to your script, especially to the `try`/`except`. Use the `logging` module or  simply `print`!

Comment: pages = total_count / 100  is  111/100. Dont know much about python but doesnt this round down to 1 so your if is never triggered

Comment: @Mihai The result is actually over 5K, I made two queries for this example

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks, I'll try to debug the app and update

Answer (score 0):

you are swallowing exceptions... don't do that.
You have no idea if `.execute()` is failing or why.

You can print the exception being raised like this:

```
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```